# Export my own prototype methods of Array and use it on a different file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, prototype

I know how to export a function, class, and variables. However, I could not find any source that clearly explains how to export a prototype method and call it on a different file. If I have a prototype method like below, how can I use it on another file?

```js
//Index.js
Array.prototype.firstItem = function() {
  return this[0]
}

export {firstItem} //I know this is wrong but how to do it in similar syntax?

//anotherFile.js
import {firstItem} from './Index.js'

const testArray = ["Thank", "You", "For", "Your", "Answer"]
console.log(testArray.firstItem())
```

Thank your for your answer

Comment: I'm pretty sure since you're just editing the prototype, anytime the file has loaded the implementation should be accessible. Have you tried just `import "./index.js"`? I would recommend against this as a method and instead recommend a function that takes an array as an argument and performs the action on the array.

Comment: What you want isn't possible, which is why you shouldn't put methods like this on the prototype to begin with. Export a regular function and do `firstItem(testArray);`